# Regex for validating date format DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: java, regex

The task is following:

> Build the regular expression for following validation:
> a) Date (Format: DD.MM.YYYY)

I wrote the following code:

```
package validator.utils;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Validator {
        
    public static boolean checkDateFormatEU(String str) {
        //* Date (Format: DD.MM.YYYY)*/
        final String regexDateFormat = "^\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}$";
        if (str == null || !(Pattern.matches(regexDateFormat, str) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        String year = str.substring(6, 9);
        //*Range from 1100 to current century*/
        final String REGEX_31_DAY_MONTHS = "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\.](0[13578]|1[02])[\\.](10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2}";
        final String REGEX_30_DAY_MONTHS = "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[\\.](0[469]|11)[\\.](10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2}";
        final String REGEX_FEB_29_DAY_MONTHS = "29[\\.](02)[\\.](((10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000)";
        final String REGEX_FEB_1_28_DAY_MONTHS = "(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\\\\.](02)[\\\\.](10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2}";
        final String REGEX_LEAP_YEAR = "((" + REGEX_31_DAY_MONTHS + ")|(" + REGEX_30_DAY_MONTHS + ")|(" + 
                                       REGEX_FEB_29_DAY_MONTHS + ")|(" + REGEX_FEB_1_28_DAY_MONTHS + "))";
        final String REGEX_NON_LEAP_YEAR = "((" + REGEX_31_DAY_MONTHS + ")|(" + REGEX_30_DAY_MONTHS + ")|(" + 
                                           REGEX_FEB_1_28_DAY_MONTHS + "))";
        final String CURRENT_REGEX =  isLeapYear(year) ? REGEX_LEAP_YEAR
                                                       : REGEX_NON_LEAP_YEAR;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(CURRENT_REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        return m.matches();
    }
    
    public static boolean isLeapYear(String str) {
        boolean yearIsLeap = false;
        int year = Integer.valueOf(str);
        if ( ( ( year % 4 == 0 ) && ( year % 100 != 0 ) ) || ( year % 400 == 0 ) ) {
            yearIsLeap = true;
        }
        return yearIsLeap;
    }
}
```

There is a drawback to this code, the date range is from 1100 year to present. How can this code be optimized in order to get rid of this drawback? How can the regex be optimized in order for the date to be of any range?

Condition: a regular expressions must be used.

Comment: I don‘t see how this could benefit from using Stream API. What would be the stream‘s content?

Comment: `Pattern.matches(str, regexDateFormat)` -> `Pattern.matches(regexDateFormat, str)`

Comment: Not sure if this is even valid code …

Comment: Are questions about optimization *wanted* (accepted) on this site? BTW regular expressions are not the indicated for validating Date CONTENT! For format it may be OK (for learning purposes), but then you *overshot* the task: for "validating date format" only the first regex (`regexDateFormat`) is sufficient (IMHO)

Comment: Yes, a check method, which must use a regular expression.

Comment: You want to reinvent a date parser - why is that when you have `DateTimeFormatter` that does that as a major part of its functionality?

Comment: See [Date checker by regex(Java) | Online editor and compiler](https://paiza.io/projects/LhIXVBrxOr-3sKTq386crw?language=java)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's really interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Condition: regular expressions must be used.* - Well there's your problem!!

This is not a good use-case for regexes.  They won't give you an efficient solution.   They certainly won't give you a good<sup>1</sup> solution.

But if you want to optimize this, consider precompiling the two regexes and saving the compiled versions in `static` variables.

---

<sup>1 - OK, that is my opinion.  But I suspect that the vast majority of experienced Java programmers would agree.  Use the `java.time.format` classes to do your validation.  That's what they are designed for.</sup>